# Make an internet connection default

Tags: 10.10, internet-connection

How do i make an internet connection default?
I have 3 connections .One of them is `Auto-etho` which is default. I would like to change this.
Please dont ask me to delete `auto-etho` cause i need it on some specific situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the network icon, Choose *Edit connections*, double-click your currently default connection, and untick the *Connect automatically* box. Check that box for the connection you'd like to have as your default one.

[image]